# Is it possible to display images or render html in a flask-table?

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, flask-table

I have a flask app using flask-sqlalchemy and flask-table.  My table displays just fine but how can I include images in one of the columns?  I have tried modifying what gets sent to the table class to be html with an image tag but the result isn't rendered html.

flask-table docs say that you can pass attributes to the table and there are column types for links and buttons but I can't see a way to pass in images or raw html so that it gets rendered.

Is this possible with flask-table or should I create the table manually?

### app.py

```
class testTable(Table):
    name = Col('Name')
    image = Col('Image')

@app.route("/table")
def table():
    
    # real app pulls items from db but effectively is the same as below
    # first item modified to be html
    items = [Item('bob','<img src="http://example.com/image.png">'),
            Item('alice', 'http://example.com/image2.png')]

    table = testTable(items)

    return render_template('table.html', table=table)
```

### table.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>Table</h1>
    
{{ table }}

{% endblock %}
```

### Results

```
------------------------------------------------------
| Name  | Image                                      |
------------------------------------------------------
| bob   | <img src="http://example.com/image.png">   |
| alice | http://example.com/image2.png              |
------------------------------------------------------
```

### In response to @grey

@grey Unfortunately it doesn't.  I tried also using the `safe` flask modifier which is supposed to render the value without escaping characters but seems to have no affect.

Here is the html source after trying a few variations or `Markup()` and `safe`

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead class="thead-dark"><tr><th>id</th><th>name</th><th>Image</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>1</td><td>test1</td><td>https://example.com/test1.png</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>no markup or safe modifier</td><td>&lt;img src=&#34;https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png&#34;&gt;</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>Using Markup()</td><td>&lt;img src=&#34;https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png&#34;&gt;</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>Using Markup() and safe modifier</td><td>&lt;img src=&#34;https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png&#34;&gt;</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your HTML string with `flask.Markup()`, it will mark the string as safe, so it will rendered as HTML without escape:

```
from flask import Markup

tems = [Item('bob', Markup('<img src="http://example.com/image.png">')),
            Item('alice', 'http://example.com/image2.png')]
```

Not tested yet, let me know if it works.